# How to show unescaped HTML in angular2 ng-content?

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a `modal` component that displays a modal popup and displayed the transcluded `ng-content` on it.

Here's what I'm trying to do in my `modal` component:

```
<modal>{{someHTMLString}}</modal>
```

When I do this, the HTML markup is escaped and displayed (which I did expect).

So I tried this:

```
<modal [innerHTML]="someHTMLString"></modal>
```

The HTML is unescaped but it somehow shows up on screen and not as a transcluded content as if `<modal>` was a regular HTML tag, and the actual modal shows up empty.

How can I have `ng-content` serve unescaped HTML?

Comment: Just a suppose, try to add `*ngIf="someHTMLString"` to your element

Comment: What about <modal><div [outerHTML]="someHTMLString"></div></modal>?

Comment: Can you replicate in Plunker?

Comment: Why is the question tagged `angularjs-ng-transclude` ? Seems an AngularJS (Angular 1) tag

Answer (score 1):

> ng-content allows for static (compile time resolution) projection of
>   content.

You can use parent div to accomplish this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <modal>
        <div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
      </modal>
  `,
})
```